# How do I create backup copies of all files in a directory?

Tags: fish

I have a directory that contains some files and I want to create backups of all files in the same directory.

I tried `cp ./* ./*.bak` (or `cp * *.bak` and several other variations including quotations) to create a copy of everything with `.bak` appended to the filenames but this hasn't worked.

I suspect I am missing something but I don't know what.

How can I achieve this?

If it is relevant, I am on Windows 10 and using Cygwin with the fish shell.

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting only 1 copy or 0 copy?

Comment: what the h\*ll... this is `fish` not `bash`??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
for f in *
    cp -r -- "$f" "$f.bak"
end
```

- `-r` means copy directories recursively,
- `--` marks the end of options, without it a filename beginning with a dash may cause problems.

Comment: want `**` for recursiv expansion

Comment: Note that the question was tagged incorrectly. OP is using fish, not bash.

Comment: @iBug added -r option instead

Comment: @Socowi fish supports for ... in ... syntax

Comment: This works nicely; would you explain what the purpose of `--` is?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy added explanation